# Trouble accessing function of inner class in Python

Tags: python, inner-classes

I am a newbie to python
I am learning how to use inner/nested classes.
I wrote the code below.
I am unable to access `display()`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.dob=self.DOB
    class DOB:
        def __init__(self,dd,mm,yyyy):
            self.dd=dd
            self.mm=mm
            self.yyyy=yyyy
        def display(self):
            return(self.dd)

p=Person('Surya')
p.DOB(11,22,3333)
p.DOB.display()
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: By using `p.DOB(11,22,3333)` you constructed a `DOB` object, but then you throw that object away. So `display(..)` indeed will error.

Comment: not to be pedantic, but a "function of a class" (inner or not) is called method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `display` function is inside a class, you need to initialize the class before trying to use it. You do initialize the class but you do not save this object anywhere.

Change your last lines to something like:

```
p = Person('Surya')
pDOB = p.DOB(11,22,3333)
print(pDOB.display())
```

Comment: @piedotpy No problem! If your problem was resolved, please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your `p.DOB` will construct a new `DOB` object, but then you throw that object away, since you do not store that object in a variable, etc. You can for example use a variable to store the returned `DOB` object, like:

```
p = Person('Surya')
dob = p.DOB(11,22,3333)
dob.display()  # will return 11
```

By using `p.DOB` you get a reference to the inner `DOB` class, and if you then call `.display()` that means there is no `self` parameter, hence the error.